# parse osrm route to List<LatLng>

Tags: java, android, osrm

I try parse osrm route to List I parse a response for request to this :

```
public class StepsItem {
    private String mode;
    private double duration;
    private double distance;
    private String name;
    private double weight;
    private String geometry;
    private String drivingSide;
    private List<IntersectionsItem> intersections;
    private Maneuver maneuver;
    private String destinations;
    private String ref;
}
```

But how I can get list og lat lon ?

how I can parse this :`mqqvHiijfBC?sWlE}J`B}IxAMBKBQ@o@LuVfEsKhBuATaFv@_ANu@PiAPwDn@_BVqEt@k@HC?yI|AqAPiBZaAPuARwANmD_DP{AFeCDeC?}DGcACaAEuBO}BU}BWg@IiFw@_UgEcB[sI_BiKqBcPyCiB]mCg@yFeAaCe@_BY_I{AuKqBqAWcHqAqEy@yF{@A?w@IsAKuBO{ACuAEQAcA?wB@s@?e@?A@kDJaGd@mC\aMfAgAJm`@pDyBR}BRyFh@yE^uBHuBB}B?qACqAGqAIqAMuC]eCe@aCi@}GeBuNuD??q@QqCs@aFqAmA]mAYsCw@{Bu@iE{AoBo@}Aq@gAc@iAg@iAi@wCuAuC}AcH_EaGsDMIgFaDwDiCk@_@{E{DuCqCsEeFw@cAy@eAoBoCuAwB_C}DgCuEo@iAuFeKMUwFmKaN_WiMyUiMaV_F{JoBsEoByEiA{CKY{BuGeCmIw@mCg@mB{AiGyA{Gq@eDq@mDq@{Do@aEm@gEk@kE}@_I]kDYkDYmDWoDa@yGScEOeEOqEIqEIyFEyFAsH@eLFwU?i@D{T@gDF_WFmT?gA`

to list lat lon

Comment: How did you get this string?

Comment: @StephaneM from curl simple like this : curl 'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407;13.428555,52.523219?overview=f

Answer (score 2):

The doc says the geometry is by default a `polyline`. And the RouteStep objects links to https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyline

So you can either use this javascript package to parse the string or add the `geometries=geojson` parameter to your request to get a geojson which lists lat and longs. See http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407;13.428555,52.523219?overview=full&geometries=geojson as an example.

Comment: So what I have toi do ?

Comment: As you are using java, the easiest seems to add the geometries=geojson parameter. You will then get an array of coordinates like this `"coordinates":[[13.3888,52.517033],[13.388782,52.517134]...`

Comment: So i do not send curl request yes ?

Comment: can I use it for free ?                         List<LatLng> latLngs = PolyUtil.decode(step.getGeometry());

Comment: What is a npmjs  ?

Comment: PolyUtil.decode(step.getGeometry()); can I use it ?